# How to remove horizontal scrollbar in tab function

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, scrollbar

I am working on twitter-Bootstrap. The webpage was running perfectly but, suddenly I don't know why a horizontal scroll bar appeared. Does anyone have any idea how to remove the scroll bar.

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Sorry i got answer from praveen Kumar.

Comment: @Kader-timon Seriously, that answer would remove scrolling from all! Anyways.

Comment: yes that horizontal scroll bar is removed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bootstrap.min.css

Change line:9 with

```
    .tab-content  
    {
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just give this style to the `.tab-content`:

```
.tab-content {overflow-x: hidden;}
```